# Teradata .Net ODBC provider encoding issues

Tags: c#, .net, encoding, odbc, teradata

I am loading data with Teradata .Net ODBC provider which works quite well, but when I load string for Japanese/Chinese or other languages that require are not in ASCII encoding I just get the substitute character (/u0001). So is there any possibility to setup the driver to return the data in UTF8? I also check the DB itself and the data are correctly stored with all not ASCII characters.

Code example I use:

```
using var cn = new TdConnection(connectionString);
        cn.Open();

        TdCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 3600;
        cmd.CommandText = query;

        using var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                var test = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("description"));

                ...other fields
            }
        }

        cn.Close();
```

Comment: Try using following and see if you get correct results : System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(string)

Comment: Specify SessionCharacterSet property as UTF8 (or UTF16) for your TdConnection.

Comment: @Fred This was actually the correct call, but it required to use TdConnectionStringBuilder, because for some reason TdConnection accepts only string as parameter...Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So at the end the correct working code is this:

```
var builder = new TdConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)
        {
            SessionCharacterSet = "UTF8"
        };

using var cn = new TdConnection(builder.ConnectionString);
cn.Open();
```

TdConnection do not accept anything else than string so TdConnectionStringBuilder is needed for additional properties.